# Files in unallocated space on SD-card

Tags: partitioning

On a SD card there are two files in a 4MB unallocated space.
How can duplicate the SD card including this space with the files ?

Comment: Please explain; unallocated space can not hold files.

Comment: A navigation program uses files in the unallocated space on the SD card to prevent copying. I want to make a backup of the SD card.blob:https://askubuntu.com/4a9defa8-4730-4adb-9c75-98d80eb70bac

Comment: A navigation program uses two files i the unallocated space to prevent copying. I want to make a backup of the SD card.